# How to switch between terminal, nerdtree and text editor?

Tags: terminal, vim, xterm

I normally switch screen in vim using ctrl+h or ctrl+l to switch between NerdTree and vim main window.
Vim8 got :term command to bring up terminal which is great!
But I cannot figure out how to switch between terminal window to nerdtree or vim window.
I have to use ctrl+w twice to switch in different windows in an order.
Is there any quick way?

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my .vimrc:

```
" Window Navigation with Ctrl-[hjkl]
noremap <C-J> <C-W>j
noremap <C-K> <C-W>k
noremap <C-H> <C-W>h
noremap <C-L> <C-W>l
```

Navigation then becomes typical Vim keystrokes, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as a modifier.

Comment: Thanks, but I found out Ctrl-H and L is no longer working with terminal.